# How parse URL contain # in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, url

I want change my site in ajax that google crawlable.

With URL :
 `Http://mysite/artices/view/#!/1234`
How i can get 1234 in above URL

Comment: The anchor portion of links are not sent to the server, unless you use Javascript to extract it and send it seperately.

Comment: Please don't: http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Comment: thanks, i think i will use pushState in html5

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a regex, so I'll give you one:

`/#!\/(\d+)/`

The first (and only) backreference is the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can't send string after "#" to server, this is the way you can do it, I have created full working example for you:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['hello'])
    {
        print_r($_POST);
       echo '<br>';
       echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '<br>';        
        die();
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#look').click(function()
                {
                    var url = 'http://localhost/tests/form.php#cool=1';
                    var paramAfter = url.split('#')[1];

                    $.post('http://localhost/tests/form.php#cool=1', "hello=1&paramAfter=" + encodeURIComponent(paramAfter), function(data)
                    {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="look">Click me</a>
        <div id="content">
            No content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```